# Want to use redissql giving error node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, key-value-store

while running this example https://github.com/JakSprats/node_Redisql/blob/master/examples/redisql_examples.js

gives me this error ,

```
~/rahul$ node redissql.js

node.js:178
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
ReferenceError: len is not defined
    at check_argc (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redisql/0.0.1/package/index.js:18:62)
    at RedisClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redisql/0.0.1/package/index.js:102:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/reach121/rahul/redissql.js:4:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:423:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:170:26)
```

I dont understand this point in this link https://github.com/JakSprats/node_Redisql
This test calls "FLUSHDB" on database 15 of redisql -> you will lose data in DB 15

what is to do with this and how we are going to do ?

Comment: Hi Rahul, I am the author of AlchemyDB(Redisql), I will contact the author of the node.js client and get back to you on it - jaksprats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you should rather use [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) module for communicating with Redis DB, because it looks like it's more actively maintained, it has bigger user base and better documentation unlike Redisql.